# Redraw WPF UI when minimized

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a C# WPF application that is software captured using Open Broadcaster Software. When the application is in the foreground or even hidden by another application, it works just fine. However, if it is actually minimized, it stps updating. This makes sense, because usually, why would you need to redraw it if nobody can see it, but this is not true for this case. Is it possible to somehow force the UI to redraw? It would be possible to call a certain method every time a UI update is needed, because the code where I would need the UI to update/redraw looks something like this (simplified):

```
private void displaySomething(int something)
{
    someRectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(...);
    // Redraw UI here
}
```

EDIT: "Update" might have been a misleading term here. "Redraw" may be better.

Comment: This would require a background thread that is started when the application is minimized.

Comment: Why haven't you tried to do it through data binding? Also can you brief me on what you are trying exactly to update? Control and it's property?

Comment: "This makes sense, because usually, why would you need to update it if nobody can see it, but this is not true for this case." OK, could you tell why you are trying to update the UI when it is Minimized? Then we can come up with better solutions.

Comment: @Dilshod As explained, it is being software captured using Open Broadcaster Software

Comment: did you try something like this? someRectangle.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { someImage.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(...); }));

Comment: @Dilshod Nope, didn't work :(

Comment: Sorry for asking lots of things. How do you know if it is working or not when it is Minimized?

Comment: @Dilshod I'm happy that you're trying to help me :) Using OBS, i can put several inputs (such as camera inputs, screen regions, images, DirectX captures and captures of single windows) onto one scene which can then be live streamed or recorded to a file. This way, I can see the activity on all captured inputs.

Comment: I am asking it because I want to simulate it in my comp and try some things if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28455/discussion-between-dilshod-and-markus-himmel)

Comment: Can you please answer this question for me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34667040/develop-win10-uwp-to-screen-share-using-open-broadcaster-software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if it works even the form is behind the other form, then do not let user to `Minimize` the form. Set `yourWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;`